# Does a HTML form need an Action/Method in order to be submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Could this be submitted to a servlet without a Action or Method? I.E.(could you use Jquery alone to send this?, or some other method?)

```
<form id="form2">
    <input type="text" value="12" name="ID"/>
    <input type="text" value="NameThatComesFirst" name="FirstName"/>
    <input type="text" value="NameThatComesLast" name="LastName"/>
    <input type=submit id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? It will answer your question.

Comment: I think I remember a JQuery plugin that would get all the field values from a form and submit them AJAX style. That ignores that typically clicking submit takes you to a whole new page so your javascript would have to handle whatever needs doing along that line.

Comment: @LeeMeador You don't need jQuery to do that.

Comment: @LeeMeador See my answer, it talks about that plugin

Comment: @Rob You don't. You can write all the javascript yourself or use somebody elses that's been already debugged. Yours will probably be smaller and may well work just fine for you.

Comment: @John "try it and see" will only tell you if something works in your browser, your version, your OS, etc, etc. Not a good way to determine if something is standards-compliant

Comment: @osullic That as no bearing on this question or my comment

Comment: @John Let me clarify. The question is: "Does a HTML form need an Action/Method in order to be submit?" Your advice is: "try it and see what happens. It will answer your question." My advice is: "Don't just try it and see, because this will only answer the question for one particular browser environment. Get the answer instead from the standards docs."

Comment: Their question was more basic than that. They just wanted to know if it was possible. They should have *trued* it instead of just asking here. Basically I was telling them to stop being lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't need to be there, by default it will submit to the currently loaded script, using a GET.

If you want to submit it with AJAX, you can define it when calling it instead of through the action/method attribute if you want using [the jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

```
$('#form2').ajaxForm( {
    url: 'comment.php', 
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function() { 
        alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    } 
});
// The suggested way is to put action and method on the form and `$.ajaxForm` 
// will find it.   
$('#form2').ajaxForm({ success: function() {
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
}});
```

You can always send the form yourself by querying the DOM and sending an AJAX request

Answer (score 0):

Default action for form submission is `METHOD="GET"` and `ACTION="SELF"`. From the [docs](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html).

*If the ACTION is missing, the URL for the document itself is assumed.*

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes if you want something to actually happen. By default if no value for the `action` attribute is specified then it will use the existing page. As for using jQuery only to handle for submission the answer is **no**. You must use some type of server-side code such as PHP, ASP, JSP, etc to handle the form. Optionally, you can also use server-side JavaScript like node.js if you want.

You can, however submit the form via ajax using jQuery. See the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: This answer is a bit messy, the answer is you don't, many people used the trick to submit to same page back in the days. As for jQuery, the question was about just how to get the data from the form and send it to the server using AJAX

Comment: That and you don't _always_ have to submit to a server application to handle the form. Just when you want to do something on the server with the form (which is _usually_ the case).